# Difference between the various material design frameworks

Tags: css, angular, material-design

Just making sure I understand the landscape here.

Material design is a way to build interfaces that Google came up with.

Material lite is googles open source implementation.

http://materializecss.com/ is just an open source non-google implementation.

And Angular2 is also creating an angular version of material lite.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you seem to be correct there are a few  non-google implementations and framework specific ones, for instance these are a few others:

- [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/) which is the open source non-google implementation for Angular, I am not aware of a specific sanctioned google implementation for angular, but you could use angular and material lite since it has no dependencies, but you would end up recreating angular material.
- [Bootstrap material](http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/#about) Same thing for Bootstrap
- [Material-Ui](http://www.material-ui.com/#/) Same thing for React
- [Ember-paper](https://github.com/miguelcobain/ember-paper)
- [Ember Material Design](http://mike1234.com/ember-material-design/) etc,etc.

on [the material lite page](https://getmdl.io/faq/index.html#existing-implementations) they expose a bit more:

> We think the community does a great job offering their own take on how Material Design should be implemented for CSS libraries.
>
> That said, the large, diverse number of implementations available are often quite liberal with their interpretation of the spec (not their fault!) and their opinions don’t always reflect what the Material Design team would consider ‘correct’. MDL was developed in close collaboration with the Material Design and Chrome UX teams and undergoes regular reviews for spec compliance. When we run into an area of the spec that isn’t yet fully fleshed out, MDL is able to offer reviewed opinions on how these should be solved in a way that tries to stay true to Material Design.